# SCIP in pyomo google colab how to use it

Tags: google-colaboratory, pyomo, gurobi, scip, ipopt

I tried to solve a problem with ipopt in google colab, but ipopt is performing poorly and struggles a lot to find an optimal solution.

For using ipopt the code lines are simple as:

```
#IPOPT solver (NLP):
!wget -N -q "https://matematica.unipv.it/gualandi/solvers/ipopt-linux64.zip"
!unzip -o -q ipopt-linux64
solver = SolverFactory('ipopt', executable='/content/ipopt')#.solve(model).write()
solver.options['max_iter'] = 3500 # standard is 3000
solver.solve(model).write()
```

In the case of SCIP, could anyone help me? What should be these lines of code for using SCIP in google colab?